# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET Error using WAMP

Tags: php, apache

I have installed WAMP on my system. My localhost site works properly, but when I pass something in the URL like `http://localhost/test.php?a=1` I get error like "*Error 101 net ERR_CONNECTION_RESET*".

Has any one experienced this same error or have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to interface to MySQL it may be an issue with the driver...

https://serverfault.com/questions/74313/what-could-cause-an-101-error-in-wamp-under-windows-7

Check your logs to see what exactly is causing the error...

Comment: Unfortunately when Apache crashes it doesn't always write the cause to its logs. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that it is WAMP's error? I googled your error and found this: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=476f762a0f84017f&hl=en

Comment: this link is dead

Answer (score 1):

@pradeep even I had the same problem. You should close the connection at the end of your page code using the connection resource. worked for me ... mysql_close($conn); where $conn is your mysql database connection resource variable which you have used to connect to mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem with **WampServer 2.1** ; and basically resolved it by installing latest version of WampServer (**WampServer 2.2D**).

Comment: I also got this problem with WampServer 3.0.6 when using PHP 5.6. I switched to PHP 7.0 and the problem disappeared.