# err-connection-reset-error-on-wamp; I figured out WHY but I don't know HOW!

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

After installing phpED, I had to change some lines on php.ini but phpmyadmin was working just fine but yesterday It started showing "Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET):" error message!

Well I can browse databases but simply can not browse tables **by clicking on their name on navigation panel.**

When I click on any table name, this a typical request, "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=databasename&token=cf4c8cd5d82_a_Token&table=table_name&pos=0"

After a bit messing around, I simply put this, "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=databasename&token=cf4c8cd5d82_a_Token&table=table_name" look **I simply removed that pos parameter** and its working fine!

But its annoying...so wondering if anyone knows what is it?

[Here is a relevant stackoverflow question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582937/err-connection-reset-error-on-wamp)

Comment: What did you modify in php.ini?

Comment: I forgot:( 

All I can remember,There were 2/3 more lines here. 


[debugger]
debugger.hosts_allow=127.0.0.1
debugger.hosts_deny=ALL
debugger.ports=7869

Comment: Check out windows event log for apache/php errors. Run `Event Viewer` and select `Administrative Events`

Comment: Check this ServerFault question: http://serverfault.com/questions/74313/what-could-cause-an-101-error-in-wamp-under-windows-7/373338#373338

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem, and i resolve it by turning off the *mod_socket*